# Extra border in images while they are in td tag, how to solve this?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a small web page and there are images in `td` but cells with images are not merging with one another.

[web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH1Xp.png)

As you can see in the image that there are borders between images.

I tried this in css but this is not working for images

```css
table, 
th, 
td {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
            <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="TC">
              <td>10/05/2018
                    <br><br>
                    Night Laser Show
                    <br><br>
                    We are happy to announce this special lasere show
                </td>
                <td>10/05/2018
                    <br><br>
                    Night Laser Show
                    <br><br>
                    We are happy to announce this special lasere show
                </td>
                <td>10/05/2018
                    <br><br>
                    Night Laser Show
                    <br><br>
                    We are happy to announce this special lasere show
                </td>
                <td>10/05/2018
                    <br><br>
                    Night Laser Show
                    <br><br>
                    We are happy to announce this special lasere show
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Please answer how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome on SO: an image can't help, you need to include a [repro] in the question itself.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: @AnasSuleman just in case you got the answer you want from the answers following, please do not forget to update the correct answers and click the little `checkmark` below the vote controls to the answer that helped you more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added padding: 0; to td

```css
table, 
th, 
td {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
            <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="TC">
              <td>10/05/2018
                    <br><br>
                    Night Laser Show
                    <br><br>
                    We are happy to announce this special lasere show
                </td>
                <td>10/05/2018
                    <br><br>
                    Night Laser Show
                    <br><br>
                    We are happy to announce this special lasere show
                </td>
                <td>10/05/2018
                    <br><br>
                    Night Laser Show
                    <br><br>
                    We are happy to announce this special lasere show
                </td>
                <td>10/05/2018
                    <br><br>
                    Night Laser Show
                    <br><br>
                    We are happy to announce this special lasere show
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @anas-suleman .. If the above answer was helpful, an upvote will make my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my answer, the think that changed is that I moved the `border-collapse: collapse;` to the table only and then I set the `th` and `td` padding to `0`

```css
/* Just Use This CSS */
/* The line you have is related to the padding of the th / td */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
    
th, td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%">
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" width="100%">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="TC">
    <td>10/05/2018
      <br>
      <br>
      Night Laser Show
      <br>
      <br>
      We are happy to announce this special lasere show
    </td>
    <td>
      10/05/2018
      <br>
      <br>
      Night Laser Show
      <br>
      <br>
      We are happy to announce this special lasere show
    </td>
    <td>
      10/05/2018
      <br>
      <br>
      Night Laser Show
      <br>
      <br>
      We are happy to announce this special lasere show
    </td>
    <td>
      10/05/2018
      <br>
      <br>
      Night Laser Show
      <br>
      <br>
      We are happy to announce this special lasere show
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `padding:0;` style to `th` and `td`